# How to set variable before callback is called?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to design a webpage. I have a function that I call to get all info needed for an individual's home page. A snippet of the code is:

```
exports.getHomePageData = function(userId, cb) {
    var pageData = {};

    pageData.userFullName = dbUtil.findNameByUserId(userId, function(err){
        if (err) cb(err);
    });
    pageData.classes = dbUtil.findUserClassesByUserId(userId, function(err){
        if (err) cb(err);
    });

    cb(pageData);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the `cb(pageData)` is being called before I even finish setting the elements.

I've seen that people use the async library to solve this, but I was wondering if there was any other way for me to do it without needing more modules.

Comment: What's `findNameByUserId` and `findUserClassesByUserId` return? From the first sight they look like async functions, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
exports.getHomePageData = function(userId, cb) {
    var pageData = {},
        filler   = function() {
          if ('userFullName' in pageData 
                && 'classes' in pageData)

            cb(null, pageData); 
        };

    dbUtil.findNameByUserId(userId, function(err, name) {
        if (err) {
          cb(err);
          return;
        }
        pageData.userFullName = name;
        filler();
    });
    dbUtil.findUserClassesByUserId(userId, function(err, classes) {
        if (err) {
          cb(err);
          return;  
        }
        pageData.classes = classes;
        filler();  
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `dbUtil.findUserClassesByUserId` and `dbUtil.findNameByUserId` are asynchronous methods; that usually indicates that they do *not* return a value, and instead use the callback to give you the data.

Both functions are most likely expecting a signature like follows:

```
function(err, data) {
  // if err is set, an error occurred, otherwise data is set with the result
}
```

Thus, your function should look like this instead:

```
exports.getHomePageData = function(userId, cb) {

  dbUtil.findNameByUserId(userId, function(err, userFullName){
      if (err) {
        cb(err);
        return;
      }  

      dbUtil.findUserClassesByUserId(userId, function(err, classes){
        if (err) {
          cb(err);
          return;
        } 

         var pageData = {
            userFullName: userFullName,
            classes: classes
         }; 

         cb(pageData);
      });
  });
}
```